# How to get clicked feedback in a listview with a focusable view (for example a button)

Tags: android, view

I have a list view that show custom list view items. I have a focusable view in every list item and I need to be able to click the button the list view item itself. I have accomplished this by adding a ClickEvent in the listview adapter. Now both views can be clicked, the problem is that the button changes color when clicked but the list view item doesn't. By change color I mean the different color a view changes into when is clicked.

Is there any possibility to get this visual feedback color back keeping the button clickable?.

P.D. To add a bit more information, I have added android:focusable="false" to the button without any luck either.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I think drawSelectorOnTop could be what you're looking for. When you use your own OnItemClickListener the default clicking on the list gets overwritten thus not giving you click feedback even if you set clickable=true, but you can specify the AbsListView (base class for ListView and GridView) to still draw a selector:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                YourAdapterClass object = (YourAdapterClass)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            }
        });
```

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, this is exactly what I'm doing now. The problem is keeping the visual feedback when the user clicks a list view item that contains a focusable view. The problem is not respond to the click.

Comment: if i understand, you've button of list view item, so it must clickListener implemenmation in getview method

Comment: Not really. The problem is that the list view item itsels does not iluminate when it is clicked. I can click the button and the list view item though.